# Find Acronym with Regular Expression Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I have 2000 page website and it contains over 500 acronyms. What Regular expression could I use to find all the acronyms in the text only? I'm using dream-weaver. Some examples would be AFD, GTDC, IJQW and so on.. these are 2 or more capitals might be bounded or surround by other characters. Such example would be (DFT) or l'WQF - any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

If dreamweaver has search via grep capability, you could just search for any string of letters with all capitals, including whatever necessary punctuation you need, e.g. `[A-Z'-]{3,}`. The `3` is the minumum number of letters in the acronym... you can change that as needed.

This would probably be better done via shell script, though, just for speed's sake. Let us know what OS you're using and someone else can leave a comment as to how to script that, as I probably don't know.

Comment: Running XP and I will try your suggestion.